# Split PHP object in multiple objects grouped by property value

Tags: php

I have an object like this, I want to create multiple objects from it. I need to check all the values of 'group' and create a new object for each different group.

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Cindy'
      'group' => string 'GROUP A'
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Carl'
      'group' => string 'GROUP A'
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Anna'
      'group' => string 'GROUP A'
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Mary'
      'group' => string 'GROUP B'
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'John'
      'group' => string 'GROUP B'
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Frank'
      'group' => string 'GROUP C'
```

For the previous example I should end up with 3 different objects like this, with a different variable for each one.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Cindy'
      'group' => string 'GROUP A'
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Carl'
      'group' => string 'GROUP A'
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Anna'
      'group' => string 'GROUP A'

array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Mary'
      'group' => string 'GROUP B'
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'John'
      'group' => string 'GROUP B'

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Frank'
      'group' => string 'GROUP C'
```

Comment: Do you actually mean objects or arrays?

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle Well, the first example is an object, and I'd like to split it in arrays or objects with a similar output as explained.

Comment: 3 different arrays contained in one big array or one variable for each array (as what your desired example looks like)?

Comment: @Mikey It would be 3 different variables for that example

Comment: The first example is an array, not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the result you want, one variable will have elements where each of them has the same *group* value: that seems a waste: just name that variable as the group, and only list the names in it. And instead of different variables, go for one *associative*(!) array that will have the group names as keys, and the corresponding names as values (arrays):

```
[
    ["GROUP A"] => ["Cindy", "Carl", "Anna"],
    ["GROUP B"] => ["Mary", "John"],
    ["GROUP C"] => ["Frank"]
]
```

I believe this is much more useful and easier to manage, than what you were thinking of.

Here is how you would produce it (assuming your input variable is `$arr`):

```
foreach ($arr as $pair) {
    $result[$pair["group"]][] = $pair["name"];
}
```

`$result` will then be as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this - I'm not sure if you know how many groups you have, but you could count them and create a loop over the chr()

```
    $tests =  [
        [
            'name' => 'Cindy',
            'group' => 'GROUP A'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Carl',
            'group' => 'GROUP A'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Anna',
            'group' => 'GROUP A'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Mary',
            'group' => 'GROUP B'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'John',
            'group' => 'GROUP B'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Frank',
            'group' => 'GROUP C'
        ]
    ];

    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($tests); echo '</pre>';

    $variables = [];
    foreach($tests as $test){
        $key = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($test['group']));
        $variables[$key][] = $test;
    }

    extract($variables);

    // echo '<pre>'; var_dump(array_keys($variables)); echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($group_a, $group_b, $group_c); echo '</pre>'; die();
```